# visual studio docker error: NU1301: Unable to > load the service index for source

Tags: .net, docker, containers, visual-studio-2022, webapi

I can not containerize .NET Web Api project in Visual Studio 2022.Below is my dockerfile:

```
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE
> 80
> 
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build WORKDIR /src COPY
> ["API.Authentication/API.Authentication.csproj",
> "API.Authentication/"] COPY ["API.Core/API.Core.csproj", "API.Core/"]
> COPY ["Infrastructure.Persistence/Infrastructure.Persistence.csproj",
> "Infrastructure.Persistence/"] COPY
> ["Core.Application/Core.Application.csproj", "Core.Application/"] COPY
> ["Core.Domain/Core.Domain.csproj", "Core.Domain/"] COPY
> ["Infrastructure.CustomAttributes/Infrastructure.CustomAttributes.csproj",
> "Infrastructure.CustomAttributes/"] COPY
> ["Shared.Kernel/Shared.Kernel.csproj", "Shared.Kernel/"] COPY
> ["Shared.ViewModel/Shared.ViewModel.csproj", "Shared.ViewModel/"] RUN
> dotnet restore "API.Authentication/API.Authentication.csproj" COPY . .
> WORKDIR "/src/API.Authentication" RUN dotnet build
> "API.Authentication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
> 
> FROM build AS publish RUN dotnet publish "API.Authentication.csproj"
> -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
> 
> FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.Authentication.dll"]
```

Receiving below error:

> Step 14/23 : RUN dotnet restore
> "API.Authentication/API.Authentication.csproj"  ---> Running in
> 36ddc34cd2a1   Determining projects to restore...
> C:\src\Shared.Kernel\Shared.Kernel.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to
> load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
> [C:\src\API.Authentication\API.Authentication.csproj]

Tried many options through google, how3ever no luck. Thanks.